# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "22/11/2019 19:47:22.793483"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm make a RoR application and I'm trying to run it on Heroku

When I run `heroku run rake db:migrate` I receive this error:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ evening-harbor-67551... up, run.2309 (Free)
D, [2019-11-22T19:47:22.752853 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.3ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(2815438446527332605)
D, [2019-11-22T19:47:22.770993 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
D, [2019-11-22T19:47:22.782317 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2019-11-22T19:47:22.792704 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
D, [2019-11-22T19:47:22.796649 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Create (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "ar_internal_metadata" ("key", "value", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "key"  [["key", "environment"], ["value", "production"], ["created_at", "22/11/2019 19:47:22.793483"], ["updated_at", "22/11/2019 19:47:22.793483"]]
D, [2019-11-22T19:47:22.797942 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.1ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2019-11-22T19:47:22.799467 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.2ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(2815438446527332605)
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "22/11/2019 19:47:22.793483"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
: INSERT INTO "ar_internal_metadata" ("key", "value", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "key"
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:611:in `async_exec_params'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:611:in `block (2 levels) in exec_no_cache'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:610:in `block in exec_no_cache'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:581:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:580:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:571:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:609:in `exec_no_cache'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `execute_and_clear'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:81:in `exec_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:130:in `exec_insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:115:in `exec_insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:162:in `insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:21:in `insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:187:in `_insert_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:734:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:184:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:70:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:140:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:346:in `block in _create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:816:in `_run_create_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:346:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:102:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:705:in `create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:342:in `block in create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:816:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:342:in `create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:308:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:52:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:315:in `block in save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:387:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:265:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:385:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:315:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:48:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:441:in `block in update!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:387:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:267:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:239:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:236:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:267:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:385:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:439:in `update!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/internal_metadata.rb:20:in `[]='
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1273:in `record_environment'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1266:in `migrate_without_lock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1363:in `with_advisory_lock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:465:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
```

I try change datestyle to 'ISO, DMY' and 'ISO, MDY' and none of the cases works.

I have another application up on heroku with the same version of ruby and rails that works correctly.

I have no idea how to fix this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres accepts and you have to use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates. 
In your example case case that would be `2019-11-22 19:47:22.793483`.

I don't sadly don't know how to get rails to use this format.